# Text htmlText and BR tag

Tags: flex3, htmltext

I have some problem with htmlText property into a Text control

```
<mx:Text id="txtTestoMessaggio" width="100%" htmlText="{contenutMessagge}" condenseWhite="true" styleSheet="{styleHTML}"/>
```

where contenutMessagge is

```
<b>test</b><br/>
<br/>
test<br />
<br />
<font color="#FF0000"><br />
red</font>
```

is showed as

"test test red"

So BR tag are ignored ... why ?

`&#13;` instead of `<br/>` works !!!

Answer (score 0):

This "html text" is not a real browser - its capabilities are extremely limited. As far as I know, `<b>/<i>`'s are generally supported.

I'd suggest you give a try on place plain newlines ('\n') instead of `<br/>`s.

Comment: I'm using condenseWhite="true" so, from doc, "If you set the condenseWhite property to true, you must use standard HTML commands, such as <br> and <p>, to place line breaks in the text field."

Comment: hmm. I think Flex 4 should fully support this feature (where your documentation ) while I have no confidence in Flex 3. It's been a long time since I use Flex 3 API and what can "html text" do is really limited.

Comment: It is Flex 3 DOC  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Text.html